# Clicking on image icon inside label does not toggle checkbox state on IE

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a pulldown menu using a form input checkbox and a label with an icon, so when the user clicks on the icon the menu opens or closes according to the checked state of the checkbox.

It works well in all browsers except for IE. What is intriguing is that if I click on text inside the label next to the icon image, it works, but not when clicking on the image icon itself.

Below follows a minimal example of this type of menu. Any hints on why this does not work only for IE (even newer versions) would be appreciated.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Menu Test</title>
<style>
.menu-items {
 position: absolute;
 border-color: #cccccc;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 padding: 4px;
 top: 40px;
}

#navigation-menu .menu-items {
 display: none;
}

#navigation-button:checked + .menu-items {
  display: inline-block;
}

#navigation-menu input[type="checkbox"], 
#navigation-menu ul span.drop-icon {
 display: inline;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<form>
 <div id="navigation-menu">
  <input type="checkbox" id="navigation-button">
  <div class="menu-items">
   <div>Option 1</div>
   <div>Option 2</div>
  </div>
  <label for="navigation-button" id="navigation-label">
   <span class="drop-icon">
    X<img src="http://uxrepo.com/static/icon-sets/dripicons/png32/24/000000/menu-24-000000.png" width="24" height="24">X
   </span>
  </label>
 </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work on IE11

Comment: @AlexanderDayan My bad.. I clicked on checkbox instead of image. Yea it doesn't work in IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following workaround for IE solves the problem:

```
label{
        display: inline-block;
    }
    label img{
        pointer-events: none;
    }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Menu Test</title>
<style>
.menu-items {
 position: absolute;
 border-color: #cccccc;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 padding: 4px;
 top: 40px;
}

#navigation-menu .menu-items {
 display: none;
}

#navigation-button:checked + .menu-items {
  display: inline-block;
}

#navigation-menu input[type="checkbox"], 
#navigation-menu span.drop-icon {
 display: inline;
}
label{
    display: inline-block;
}
label img{
    pointer-events: none;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<form>
 <div id="navigation-menu">
  <input type="checkbox" id="navigation-button">
  <div class="menu-items">
   <div>Option 1</div>
   <div>Option 2</div>
  </div>
  <label for="navigation-button" id="navigation-label">
   <span class="drop-icon">
    X<img src="http://uxrepo.com/static/icon-sets/dripicons/png32/24/000000/menu-24-000000.png" width="24" height="24">X
   </span>
  </label>
 </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that you have unneccessary ul in the line `#navigation-menu ul span.drop-icon {`

Comment: That was it. I had no idea that images could sink events and not pass them to the parent elements, at least in Internet Explorer. Also that style was a remainder of previous edits. Thank you for solving the issue.